# Hello I have been trying this command $sudo apt install libfuse2 bu it shows the error;; can anyone help me

Tags: command-line, apt, software-center

```
nabin@:~$ sudo apt install libfuse2
E: Malformed line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: "Malformed line" means that there's something wrong with a specific line in the file that is specified. You will want to look at the second line in your `xenial.list` file and correct the error. Please note that Xenial (Ubuntu 16.04) is also long out of support on this site.

Comment: I looked at line 2 of the xenial list. It is empty. and I also replaced the code with that one from GitHub but sill It doesnt work. Is there any way out??

Comment: Rename the file to something with a different extension, like `xenial.list.backup`, and try again. Unless you are really running a 16.04 version you won't need it anyway.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm